# Git ignore file for Xcode projects is ignoring .swift files

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, git

Yesterday I added a git ignore file to my Xcode project and during version control is ignoring every .swift file I create so those are not appearing in my commits.
Other member of my team are having problems with my changes because of this.
They can side the file in the left side of Xcode but can not enter to it.

What should I’ve been looking for in the git ignore file ?

**.gitignore**:

```
Pods/ActionSheetPicker-3.0/LICENSE
...
...
...
Pods/Target Support Files/STPopup/STPopup.xcconfig
.DS_Store
**/.DS_Store
*/.DS_Store
## User settings
xcuserdata/
## compatibility with Xcode 8 and earlier (ignoring not required starting Xcode 9)
*.xcscmblueprint
*.xccheckout
codi-fix-demo.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/*
codi-fix-demo.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/*
```

Comment: Perhaps you should share you `.gitignore` file so that we can see what you included in it

Comment: Sure, thanks for helping: www.justpaste.it/5j12h

Comment: Why did you add  you add each individual `Pod` and their files like that? You could have just added `Pods/` to your `.gitignore` and that would have ignored all those files. I think you are going to have to revert the commit where you added the `.gitignore`.  Here is a template `.gitignore` that you can use https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Swift.gitignore

Comment: I edited your question by putting your `.gitignore` content on the question instead of being in an external website, because it's against the guidelines of the community, I think it's also better for the reader to have everything ready instead of redirecting in other websites.

Answer (score 3):

**1) Take a look at your .swift files** through `Finder` if they are in the right directories/path folders/subfolders.

Then take a look on each of them, if they are **greyed-out** on the `Project Navigator` from Xcode or if they are **red**. In both case click on the file from the Project Navigator and from the `Inspector` (menu on the right) check `Location` and `Full Path` if they are correct, try to click on the icon circled in red in this screenshot and find where your swift file is and confirm it.

[image]

**2) Your .gitignore looks fine** in the sense that didn't affect your `.swift` files but you could improve it and reduce it to this:

```
Pods/
*.DS_Store
.build/
xcshareddata/
xcuserdata/
## Build generated
build/
DerivedData/
## compatibility with Xcode 8 and earlier (ignoring not required starting Xcode 9)
*.xcscmblueprint
*.xccheckout
codi-fix-demo.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/*
codi-fix-demo.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/*
```

Comment: Thank you. I've modified the .gitignore file already. Hopefully once if push the changes the next files that I create will be there. Meanwhile, I'll share the files with my teammate.

Comment: @MichelOrtega don't forget to choose it as the right answer if that matches your question issues and helped you in solving your problem.